# Hide or Disable CheckBox in Last Row of DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have a datagridview that is loading by the datatable..

```
//dgvApprovazione is my DataGridView
//dt is my DataTable
dgvApprovazione.DataSource = dt;
```

DataTable represent part of table in db.

I have this situation :
[image]

I try with this code

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvApprovazione.Rows)
{
    if (row.Cells[3].Value != null)
    {
        //CheckBox ckb = row.Cells[3] is check
        if ((Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells[3].Value)) == true)
        {
            row.Cells[3].ReadOnly = true;
        }
    }
}
```

But i think that problem is in setting `DataTable dt`... 
How i delete that checkbox ?!? 
And is a second question .. how i delete a last row in datatable *AND* in datagridview .

Comment: Do you only want to delete that checkbox or the whole empty row?

Comment: set [`DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoaddrows(v=vs.110).aspx) to false. This is removes the last entire row.

Comment: Now I'm in front of situation ... I would learn both... 
How i delete only checkbox..  and 
How i delete an empty rows from datatable

Comment: `AllowUserToAddRows` run good for delete last rows... But I Think that _it's more correct_ delete last row in datatable.. If it's possible..... Or even better in phase of loading after query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable adding new row (remove the last new row):

- Set [`DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.allowusertoaddrows(v=vs.110).aspx) to `false`.

To keep adding new row enabled but hide and disable CheckBox

- Handle `CellPainting` and don't render the check box
- Handle `CellContentClick` and check if the cell is in the last row don't do anything
- To prevent an automatic check and uncheck, set the column `ReadOnly` property to `false`.

---

If you want to don't render the check box, you should handle [`CellPainting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting(v=vs.110).aspx) event and prevent drawing the check box:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
{
    // I suppose your check box is at column index 0
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex == dataGridView1.NewRowIndex)
    {
        e.PaintBackground(e.ClipBounds, true);
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

This doesn't prevent a click on the cell, if you want to prevent running the logic that you have on click for last row, you should handle [`CellContentClick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick(v=vs.110).aspx) event and check if the clicked cell is not the new row:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // I suppose your check box is at column index 0
    // To exclude header cell:  e.RowIndex >= 0  
    // To exclude new row:      celle.RowIndex!=dataGridView1.newRowIndex

    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.RowIndex!=dataGridView1.newRowIndex)
    {
        //Put the logic here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To delete last row `DataGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(DataGridView.Rows.Count - 1)`

Same thing for: `DataTable.Rows.RemoveAt(DataTable.Rows.Count - 1)`

To not allow new empty rows at all set `DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows`

Also there is not much of a point in deleting that checkbox from logic perspective as it belongs to the checkbox column and is supposed to be there.